# How to add an attachment image with path to Slack message on Fastfile - Fastlane

Tags: ruby, slack-api, fastlane

I have a **Fastfile** that runs a Slack message after every lane. I am trying to post an image stored locally with every message sent, but it doesn't work with a path. `image_path` is not working either.

This is my `Slack` message

```
after_all do |lane|
    # This block is called, only if the executed lane was successful
    slack(
       message: "Successfully deployed new App Update, with attachment_properties",
       payload: {  # Optional, lets you specify any number of your own Slack attachments.
         "Build Date" => Time.new.to_s
       },
       attachment_properties: {
         image_url: "./fastlane/screenshot.jpg", #The poath the screenshot is stored
         fields: [{
           title: "Attachment",
           value: "Frameit Screenshots",
           short: true
           }]
       }
     )
  end
```

Comment: If this library just submits the content of `attachment_properties` to Slack directly, then `image_url` will need to be a publicly accessible URL as outlined here: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments